# How to save user's data without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where users can post there favorite quotes, i want them to be able to see all the quotes that they have posted till now as "Posts By Me, but I don't want to use authentication, is it even possible?

Comment: create a public page?

Comment: you can use a cookie, but if they log in from a different device or clear their cookies they won't be able to access it